# Jquery each on DOM element - Push in array error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use each() function on my DOM to get field dynamically added.
But I hava a probleme with this code :

```
  var nouvelle_entree=new Object();
    $('div[name="declaration-ligne-entree"]').each(function () {
    nouvelle_entree.name=$(this).children('input[name="system-input-name"]').val();
    nouvelle_entree.values=$(this).children('input[name="system-input-valeur"]').val().split(",");
    console.log(nouvelle_entree);
    mockSystem.input.push(nouvelle_entree);
    });
    console.log(mockSystem.input);
```

The push function always push the last child and not the other but on my console log in have the good values.

> log  1 : {name: "a", values: Array(1)}
>
> log 2 : {name: "b", values: Array(1)}
>
> log 3: [
>
> {name: "b", values: Array(1)}
>
> {name: "b", values: Array(1)}
>
> ]

Why ?

Comment: Short answer is you are pushing the exact same object into array each time, and overwriting it's values every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 3):

> Why ?

Since in every iteration you're overwriting the same object `nouvelle_entree`.

You need to define the object `nouvelle_entree` in every iteration not just the first time, else the variable will always contains the informations of the last iteration, e.g :

```
$('div[name="declaration-ligne-entree"]').each(function() {
  var nouvelle_entree = {};

  nouvelle_entree.name = $(this).children('input[name="system-input-name"]').val();
  nouvelle_entree.values = $(this).children('input[name="system-input-valeur"]').val().split(",");

  mockSystem.input.push(nouvelle_entree);
});

console.log(mockSystem.input);
```